# Matrix Multiplication function won't compile inside the main

Tags: c

This is a simple matrix multiplication, code won't compile. I also want to take the function outside. I know I have to have global variables and function declaration, but the code won't even compile inside the main.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#define N 10

float *A[N], *B[N], *C[N];



int main(){

  int count = 0, i,j, k;


  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    A[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    B[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    C[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));


   for (i = 0; i <  N; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        A[i][j] = ++count;
        B[i][j] = count;
        }

    void multiply(float* A, float* B, int n) {
       for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
           for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
             C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
    }

          for (i = 0; i <  N; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
              printf("%f\t", C[i][j] );

}
```

Comment: you cannot define a method inside another method, remove the line with void multiplay, and the end closing bracket

Comment: `multiply` is a _nested_ function. While that's _possible_, it's an advanced technique [and rarely used in `c` code]. Also, you _define_ the function, but you _don't_ actually _call_ it. So, it does nothing. Move the definition of `multiply` to file scope [above `main`]--you'll be glad you did. And add a _call_ to it in `main`

Comment: C does not specify a function defined inside another.

Comment: @pavel.lazar A function may be _declared_ inside another.  It is the _definition_ of a function inside another that is an issue.

Comment: Mahan Agha Zahedi: " I know I have to have global variables" --> Global variables are not required here.

Comment: thanks, @chux-ReinstateMonica, will update, my C/C++ is rustier than I thought

Comment: Plus, you're defining/allocating (e.g.) `A` as a 1D array (of dimension `N`) but, you're trying to access it as a 2D array of dimension `NxN`. Try: `float A[N][N]` (i.e. _not_ a pointer) and skip the `malloc` calls [for now]. Likewise, for `B` and `C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A , B and C are defined at the top as global as an array of pointers to float

inside your multiply function you have locally redefined them as a pointer to a float..

this is why the multiplication fails inside multiply.
you are pretending that A and B are arrays of pointers to float again.. and they have been locally scoped as pointers to float.

Does this do what you were expecting ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#define N 10

float *A[N], *B[N], *C[N];

void multiply( float *a[], float *b[], float *c[], int n ) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
           for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
                c[i][j] += (a[i][k]) * b[k][j];
}


int main(){

  int count = 0, i,j, k;


  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    A[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    B[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    C[i] = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));


   for (i = 0; i <  N; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
     {
        A[i][j] = ++count;
        B[i][j] = count;
     }
     
    multiply(A,B, C, N);


    for (i = 0; i <  N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%f\t", C[i][j] );

}
```

if so please explain it back to me how this works

Comment: what I tried to do was to create a 2D array by creating an array of pointers. Would you please guide me through this, I am gonna do linear algebra, so I really need to master this multi array handling in C.

Comment: Yes, that's it!
and if I want to return the matrix instead of  a void function, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your multiply function definition inside main makes it a nested function which is not allowed in C. You can **call** as many functions inside a function but **cannot define** a new function inside an already existing one.
Plus you have also not called the multiply function.